# How do i find an ID of an album to make the request to imagur API?

Tags: ios, swift, imgur

I'm trying to invoke an http request to imgur API. I need to get any album of images back from the API. In the request body is necessary to specify the link with the ID of the album. How do i find this ID?

Comment: Check the Imgur [API documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest)

Answer (score 0):

The album ID is the last part of the URL to said album.

https://imgur.com/gallery/**XYZ**